# R-studio can't find file path for Git. Using M1 Macbook, Version (11.2)

Tags: git, filepath

I've been trying to link R-studio with Git and it keeps coming up with the "Git was not detected on the file path". Using "which git" in the terminal retrieves "/usr/local/bin/git" but when I manually set that location for the SVN, it still doesn't work. I think this may have to do with the new MacBook update but I can't seem to get anything to work. I installed git with git-2.15.0-intel-universal-mavericks.dmg.

Comment: I've also noticed that R Studio no longer sees Git after the recent macOS update.  It was working prior to it just fine, now I no longer see the Git tab and when I try to start a new project from version control see the "Git was not detected on the system path" -- I am wondering if it has to do with R Studio running via Rosetta2 layer, and Git running natively?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing where you would supply the path, unless you've mistyped:

You would want to add the path `/usr/local/bin/git` to the *"Git executable:"* section; SVN is a different version control framework

Ensure the above is true.  Also I found that sometimes even after specifying the path, it doesn't seem to function right away, but when I quit R Studio and relaunch, I see the Git tab and can start a new project using Git